# cannot execute jython script using wsadmin.sh

Tags: scripting, jython, websphere-8

I am trying to automate application deployment in a Websphere 8 server using wsadmin and jython scripts.

I would like to list all applications that are running in my server (just to test my setup)

```
wsadmin.sh -lang jython -c 'AdminApp.list()'
```

When I run the above command in terminal, I get no response back/no errros. I tried moving the AdminApp command to a separate file (listApplications.py), same result

```
wsadmin.sh -lang jython listApplications.py
```

Are there any pre requisites to using the wsadmin.sh? How to look for logs when wsadmin.sh is being executed?

Answer (score 1):

Provide full path of wsadmin.sh For example:

/opt/IBM/.../wsadmin.sh -lang jython -c "print AdminApp.list()"

Answer (score 0):

According to [this article](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/info/exp/ae/txml_listapp.html) I suggest to try:

```
wsadmin.sh -lang jython -c 'print AdminApp.list()'
```

instead of

```
wsadmin.sh -lang jython -c 'AdminApp.list()'
```

Comment: Thanks @Lukasz. I still get the same result... no response and no errors on the console `wsadmin.sh -lang jython -c 'print AdminApp.list()'`